# Keyword search using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to identify observations from my data using a list of keywords.However, the search results contains observations where only part of the keyword matches. For instance the keyword `ice` returns `varices`. I am using the following code

```
select * 
from mytab
WHERE myvar similar to'%((ice)|(cool))%';
```

I tried the `_tsquery` and it does the exact match and does not include observations with `varices`. But this approach is taking significantly longer to query. (2 keyword search for similar to `'% %'` takes 5 secs, whereas `_tsquery`takes 30 secs for 1 keyword search.I have more than 900 keywords to search)

```
select * 
from mytab
where myvar @@ to_tsquery(('ice'));
```

Is there a way to query multiple keywords using the `_tsquery` and any way to speed the querying process.

Comment: What is the type of `myvar` and can you give an example of some entries?

Comment: `myvar` - type character eg: 'liver disease\ Esophageal varices'

Comment: In your example, "ice" shouldn't match to anything, but "liver" or "disease" should, correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I was expecting not to get a hit with this observation since there is no `ice` or `cool` in myvar. But instead I am getting observations containing 'varices' or 'services"

Comment: And is `myvar` indexed?

Comment: Yes dataset is indexed

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using keywords in a relational sense rather than having a running list of them under one field, which makes for terrible performance. Instead, you can have a table of keywords with id's as primary keys and have foreign keys referring to `mytab`'s primary keys. So you'd end up with the following:

```
keywords table 
id | mytab_id | keyword  
----------------------
1      1        liver
2      1        disease
3      1        varices
4      2        ice

mytab table
id | rest of fields
---------------------
 1    ....
 2    ....
```

You can then do an inner join to find what keywords belong to the specified entries in `mytab`:

`SELECT * FROM mytab 
  JOIN keywords ON keywords.mytab_id = mytab.id 
  WHERE keyword = 'ice'`

You could also add a constraint to make sure the `keyword` and `mytab_id` pair is unique, that way you don't accidentally end up with the same `keyword` for the same entry in `mytab`.